# Pandas: filter by date proximity

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a frame like:

```
     id         title       date
0  1211  jingle bells 2019-01-15
1  1212  jingle bells 2019-01-15
2  1225      tom boat 2019-06-15
3  2112      tom boat 2019-06-15
4  3122      tom boat 2017-03-15
5  1762      tom boat 2017-03-15
```

An `item` is defined as the group of `id` with the same `title` and with `date` within 70 days of the first. I need a dictionary of `id`s grouped by `title` if `date` is within 70 days of each other. Expected outcome here is:

```
d = {0: [1211,1212], 1: [1225,2112], 2: [3122,1762]}
```

Any given `title` can have uncapped number of dictionary entries or just one. `id` are unique to one title. At the moment, I do something like:

```
itemlist = []
for i in list(df.title):
    dates = list(df.loc[df.title==i,'date'])
    if (max(dates)-min(dates)).days > 70:
        items = []
        while len(dates)>0:
            extract = [i for i in dates if (i-min(dates)).days<70]
            items.append(list(df.loc[(df.title==i)&(df.date.isin(extract)),'id'])
            dates = [i for i in dates if i not in extract
    else:
        items = [list(df.loc[df.title==i,'id'])]
    itemlist += items
d = {j:i for i in range(len(itemlist)) for j in itemlist[i]}
```

It doesn't quite work yet, I'm bugfixing. That said, I feel like this is a lot of iteration - any ideas on how to do this better?
another acceptable output would be a list of dataframes, one per `item`.

Answer (score 1):

I think sorting your dataframe can help you solve the problem much more efficiently.

```
df = df.sort_values(['title', 'date'])

itemlist = []
counter = 0 # to get items at constant time

for title in set(df.title):
    dates = df.loc[df['title']==title].date.tolist()
    item = []
    min_date = dates[0]
    for date in dates:
        if (date-min_date).days>70: # we need a new item
            itemlist.append(item) # append original item
            item = [df.iloc[counter, 0]] # new item
            min_date = date
        else:
            item.append(df.iloc[counter, 0])
        counter += 1
    itemlist.append(item)

d = {i:j for i,j in enumerate(itemlist)}

print(d)
```

Even though the code became a bit long, there are only two loops (except the last one to change the `list` into `dict`) and it loops `n_rows` time in total, which means it only looks at every row once.
The use of `counter` is to use `df.iloc` which uses positional index (instead of labels or conditional statements like `df.loc`), hence computes faster-with O(1).